# How to delete GRUB entirely from GRUB rescue and boot Windows only

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, grubrescue

I installed Ubuntu (twice actually) onto the same drive. I wanted to 'try again' since one of them didn't install correctly and the other installed differently, but it worked.

I was getting frustrated with the GRUB menu because it was really sloppy (There were two Windows options - one with the Windows bootloader to go into Ubuntu, and two different versions of Ubuntu from the first install for some reason and memtest, etc.).

In my attempts at getting rid Ubuntu to do a fresh installation, I went ahead and deleted the partitions that weren't swap or main via Windows 7. As I said, I am a noob.

Now, even though I though I completely got rid of Ubuntu, including the GRUB menu, when I boot my PC I am brought directly to GRUB Rescue. And from what I've found from other forums, GRUB rescue isn't even completely functional for me (it doesn't recognize any commands that it should support besides `ls`. It also returns `unknown filesystem` for any partition I try to view or boot.)

Is there any way that I can boot straight into Windows? I fear I may have gone about deleting those partitions in the wrong way. If so, what are my options?

Comment: Along with this, I don't have access to a Windows CD, but can get one for Ubuntu if necessary. I did try to boot from a flash drive with the Ubuntu iso though, and that brought me to the grub rescue prompt as well.

Comment: same problem here and I don't have any CD.How did you solve it ?

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you are using Windows 7 (this should also work on Vista and Windows 8):

1. Put the Windows 7 installation/Upgrade disc in the disc drive, and then start the computer (set to boot from CD in BIOS).
2. Press a key when you are prompted.
3. Select a language, a time, a currency, a keyboard or an input method, and then click Next.
4. Click Repair your computer.
5. Click the operating system that you want to repair (Windows 7 in this case), and then click Next.
6. In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Command Prompt.
7. Once in the command prompt, type exactly `Bootrec.exe /FixMbr` and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. You will see "operation completed successfully." (Doesn't even take a second. Don't be alarmed )
8. Reboot and set BIOS to boot from the HDD again.

GRUB will be overwritten in step 7 and Windows bootloader will once again take control of loading your OS(s).

[Source](http://windowsforum.com/threads/how-to-remove-grub-loader-and-get-windows-7-boot-loader-back-uninstalling-linux.34709/)

Comment: I had Ubuntu 14.04 installed alongside windows 8.1 and after removing Ubuntu, i had the same problem. and this worked for me. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't if its possible to get rid of grub entirely, and boot just windows (without simply reinstalling windows), but you can fix your grub - just get an ubuntu live cd (or USB) and use Boot-Repair - the 2nd option listed at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 3):

Start windows recovery follow the instructions to get to a command line prompt, then type

```
BootRec.exe /fixmbr
```

reboot and you're all good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your partitions are still in order, you can fix the MBR in Windows Recovery and it will boot back into Windows.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

If you do have an Ubuntu partition, it won't be wiped so you might need to do additional clean up no your partitions afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Put the Windows 7 installation/Upgrade disc in the disc drive, and then start the computer (set to boot from CD in BIOS).

- Press a key when you are prompted.
- Select a language, a time, a currency, a keyboard or an input method, and then click Next.
- Click Repair your computer.
- Click the operating system that you want to repair (Windows 7 in this case), and then click Next.
- In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Command Prompt.
- Once in the command prompt, type exactly Bootrec.exe /FixMbr and then press ENTER. You will see "operation completed successfully." (Doesn't even take a second. Don't be alarmed )
- Reboot and set BIOS to boot from the HDD again.

GRUB will be overwritten in step 7 and Windows bootloader will once again take control of loading your OS(s).

Then load your bootable pen drive or CD so,your your problem will be solved.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to be worried about. It is a common problem in many cases.

There are two approaches to solve it. Here I am mentioning the better approach only.

Insert live CD or live USB of Ubuntu.

Power on and bring the BIOS menu by continuously pressing the appropriate function key for your laptop build.

Go to BOOT tab, move below and select the live cd or USB. Press F6 to move it to the top of boot order. Press F10 and Enter to save and exit.

Now the laptop will boot from live CD or USB. Open gparted and check windows partitions. If all the partitions are intact then there is nothing to worry about. However if the system partition for windows is not there then there is no alternative other than a complete reinstallation of windows.

Assuming that the windows partition is untouched, start Ubuntu installation. Ubuntu boot loader will be able to recognize the presence of windows OS. Select the option "Install Ubuntu along with Windows". Continue with the installation process. Then when prompted for reboot and do remember to remove the installation media.

Now the GRUB menu will appear having the options

```
*Ubuntu

*Ubuntu Advanced

*Windows Bootloader
```

Select Ubuntu to boot Ubuntu

Select Windows to boot Windows

Thats it