# cannot boot neither of my dual-boot OS

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, usb, grubrescue

So I wanted to install Ubuntu 13.10, along side my Windows, as dual-boot. But then the installation threw error. Apparently the installation file was corrupted when making the USB bootable. Anyway, I couldn't finish the installation.

So I just restarted my machine and I didn't get the option of booting OS. I just got to a black screen which had only

grub rescue>

waiting for me to type some magical commands. Of course I don't know what to do, because even -help, -h or any of this type was not a recognized command.

So I ran a live Desktop version of Ubuntu, from the USB, and tried to remake it bootable through the integrated Startup Disk Creator. I got unhandled exceptions.

Now I am stuck without being able to boot any of my OS and not knowing what to do. Yay!

Help, please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GRUB, boot from a Live USB and use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to get it back.

As for Windows, I'm not so sure. I've heard about using an install disc - that might be something to look into.

Comment: Using that tool was freaking easy to fix the problem. Now I am back in my Windows and will install Ubuntu again... :)

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Check this related post... [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228763/how-to-delete-grub-entirely-from-grub-rescue-boot-windows-only?rq=1)

I would try and re-build the MBR and boot to windows OS first. Then try re-install of Ubuntu.

Comment: yeah, I also wanted to just jump over this problem, so I can boot my Windows and remake the flash drive bootable again and then install Ubuntu all over.