# Dual Boot problems (Win 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10), Boot-repair didnt work

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, grubrescue

I have preinstalled Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu that I installed a week ago on my Laptop Lenovo E530. After my first installation of my Ubuntu 13.10 as Dual Boot, I could not to log in to Windows again, only Ubuntu.

Today I decided to fix this problem with Boot-repair. I used a bootable version of my Ubuntu on my USB to log in, then I downloaded the Boot-repair via Terminal. Then in Boot-repair I choosed the Recommended repair and followed all the instructions, including confirmation of the removing my Grub 2. After that, when I restart the computer, everything what I see now is black screen with error message:

> error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
>
> Entering rescue mode...
>
> grub rescue>

Now I cant log in to any operating system. Probably the Grub doesn't load.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Same question http://askubuntu.com/questions/386467/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found-in-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 1):

Best is to reïnstall Grub with an live-cd.

Step 1)
From a live cd open an terminal

Step 2)
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt (sdXY should by your root Example /dev/sda5)

Step 3)
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev && sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts && sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc && sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

Step 4)
sudo chroot /mnt

Step 5
grub-install /dev/sdX && update-grub

Step 6
exit && sudo umount /mnt/dev && sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts && sudo umount /mnt/proc && sudo umount /mnt/sys && sudo umount /mnt

Reboot and here you go.

Answer (score 1):

if you have the windows disc, and the Windows Recovery option during the install.
you may also try the ubuntu boot disc itself and the problem with the grub will be alright!
for further help from windows, use this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

you can find the detailed description of how overwrite the grub, from the second reply of this link [How to delete GRUB entirely from GRUB rescue and boot Windows only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228763/how-to-delete-grub-entirely-from-grub-rescue-boot-windows-only?rq=1)  in this case, the windows will take over the control and ubuntu will be shown as an option!