# How do I get rid of GRUB without formatting my HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I couldn't find an answer to my question so I thought I would ask my own. Today I tried to install Kali Lunix from a USB drive. I WAS running a dual boot with Ununtu and Windows 8.1. Every time I tried to boot from the USB it would go to a purple screen and I would get impatient and shut my laptop off because it didnt do anything. Later research found out that the screen just black out. I used the windows partition manager to format the Ubuntu partition that I had made and turned it into free space.

Now when I boot up I get stuck with GRUB. I'm still not able to boot from my USB, and yes, its first on the boot list. I even have exited grub and tried to boot from USB but it just re-opens GRUB. When I choose to boot from my HDD it tells me that can boot from: ubuntu, Windows Boot Manager, and Ubuntu. The last two just boot up windows. ubuntu just boots back up GRUB because I no longer have any Ubuntu files.

I assume that my laptop still thinks that I have Ubuntu on it. I've tried the Advanced Boot from the Recovery tab in the Windows settings but I cant figure out how to delete the ubuntu and Ubuntu entries. I would really like to remove GRUB w/o formatting my HDD. I don't have a way to back up my windows files because I have over 200Gb of things I need to save. Any help with this issue would be absolutely wonderful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: maybe also https://askubuntu.com/questions/228763/how-to-delete-grub-entirely-from-grub-rescue-boot-windows-only helps...

Comment: This question isn't really a duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on); it's much more specific and limited than that question.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it's apparent that you're running an EFI-based computer. There are several ways to do what you want, but I first want to note a caveat: Some tools (such as Boot Repair, if you activate certain advanced options) move and rename EFI boot loaders in order to work around EFI bugs. If you've used such a tool on your computer in the past, doing the "right" thing can actually make matters worse. I don't think that doing as I describe here will do that, but it's possible that this procedure won't work if your files have been moved and renamed. That out of the way, one way to get rid of GRUB on such a system is as follows:

1. Boot to Windows using your built-in boot manager.
2. Open an *Administrator* Command Prompt window. In Windows 7, you'd do this by right-clicking the Command Prompt item and selecting "Run as Administrator." This is probably different in Windows 8, though.
3. Type `mountvol P: /S`. This should mount the ESP as `P:`. (You can change that identifier if you like.)
4. **Back up the contents of `P:`.** You could do this with [`xcopy`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true), which copies entire directory trees; or use a command-line Zip utility.
5. Type `cd P:`.
6. Explore the files on `P:`. There should be a directory called `EFI\ubuntu`. Delete it. There may be other suspicious files or directories, but don't delete them just yet. Be especially careful to *not* delete the `EFI\Microsoft` directory. Note that you'll need to do all this in the Administrator Command Prompt window, using commands like `dir` and `del`.

When you reboot, the computer should boot straight to Windows. If it doesn't, you can go back in and review any other files or directories. Most Windows machines have an `EFI\Microsoft` directory on the ESP, and possibly a directory for the computer's manufacturer, but that's it. Anything else is suspect, especially if it's got a Linux-related name -- for instance, if `EFI\fedora` is present, it's likely to be the boot loader from a leftover Fedora installation.

There are alternatives to this approach. For instance, you could use [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) in Windows or `efibootmgr` in an emergency Linux boot to change the boot order. Many EFIs provide similar functionality in their built-in setup utilities, but the details of how to use these tools varies from one machine to another. Re-ordering the boot options may pose slightly less risk of doing something catastrophically wrong than deleting the Ubuntu files from the ESP, but it also won't fully "get rid of" GRUB, in the sense that GRUB will still be on the hard disk.

Note also that there's a possibility that GRUB is installed in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, in which case the easiest and safest solution is to disable this support. Many Ubuntu installation instructions recommend enabling this support, but that's a Bad Idea, IMO. If you did this, you should follow those instructions in reverse to undo the damage and get your system back to booting in EFI-only mode.