# -error: no such partition -Entering rescue mode -grub rescue>

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, windows-7, boot-partition

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 along with windows 7. In windows disk management I tried to shrink volume to occupy free space while doing it in `C:\` drive (where my windows and Linux installed). It takes to much time to retrieving disk size for shrink (usually it appears once we right click on the disk and clicking the shrink volume). But in my case it does not appear for long time so I decided to restart the system it ended up and saying this:

```
error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode
grub rescue>
```

**What I did**: I tried to extend the one partition(disk) by deleting unused partition(disk), partition deleted successfully, When I tried to extend this free space to the other partition, the following error occurs:

Then I did so far:

```
grub rescue>ls
grub rescue>(hd0)(hd0,msdos6)(hd0,msdos5)(hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue>ls (hd0,msdos*)
```

# I tried this for all disk but it saying '`unknown filesystem`'.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @shivsperfect, I tried to edit your question a little bit, could you please edit you question again as  it is not clear what you tried and what error you got. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have already fixed this by now, but if you havent here is a soultion that worked for me

If you somehow can get a Windows 7/8/10 USB/DVD installation media you can overrule GRUB boot loader

1) Start Windows 10 USB from boot manager

2) Choose language

3) Repair your pc

4) Click the OS you wanna repair

5) Find Command Prompt

6) Then type: Bootrec.exe /FixMbr

7) Voila, now you are free to reboot and change the boot order

Found the solution for myself some time ago here: [How to delete GRUB entirely from GRUB rescue and boot Windows only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228763/how-to-delete-grub-entirely-from-grub-rescue-boot-windows-only)