# grub "unknown filesystem" when trying to install windows

Tags: grub2, windows-10, mbr

Someone sold me a computer that used to run ubuntu (16.04?). I am trying to install Windows 10 on it (NOT dual boot)

The original owner removed (reformatted?) the partitions before handing it to me so that I wouldn't see their data.

I am able to boot from the windows USB install media, go through the install but when the install restarts, I get:

```
error:unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode
grub rescue>
```

something/grub is remaining on the harddrive even though it shows no partition.

I can't boot in windows, I can't boot in ubuntu. I'm not trying to recover/rescue anything. The only solution I see at this point is to buy a new SSD that doesn't have grub/mbr whatever

I tried to google for it but most solutions appear to be geared at dual booting and recovering existing installations.

From [How to delete GRUB entirely from GRUB rescue and boot Windows only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228763/how-to-delete-grub-entirely-from-grub-rescue-and-boot-windows-only) I tried booting from the windows 10 usb install media, SHIFT+F10 to get the command line, ran

`bootrec /mbr` (successful), 
`bootrec /fixboot` (access denied)
 But when windows tries to install and reboot I get back to grub rescue

When I type `ls` from grub rescue I see:

```
(hd0) (hd0, msdos1) (hd1) (hd1, msdos1) (hd2) (hd2, msdos1)
```

I believe there are only 2 physical disks an SSD (or NVRAM) and a large spinner. 
At least in windows install that's all I see. I'm guessing hd1 and hd2 are due to the MS install splitting the large disk into two partitions?

help?

Comment: During Windows installation use advanced options concerning disk configuration, delete all partitions and create new ones from scratch. Since there's no Ubuntu, but you're trying to install windows, ask this question on superuser.com. That resource is much more appropriate for this type of questions.

Comment: I thought grub was part of ubuntu/linux, and I have done what you suggest (should have mentioend it) but still getting grub rescue

Comment: Normally windows rewrites mbr, but it seems that your mbr does not allow rewriting. I could suggest you to refresh grub from ubuntu live cd after windows installation if it will be possible. It could find windows partition and be able to boot it. Also make sure that secure boot is disabled in bios. You could try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71634/341457

Answer (score 1):

OK I was finally able to fix it with the following:

boot from ubuntu 18.04 liveCD (on USB key)  then:
sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda

After reboot the grub rescue prompt was gone. I still ended up in a weird reboot loop during windows install, I pulled the spinner drive, and then installed windows on the SSD, then once windows booted I plugged the spinner back it, removed partitions and reformatted.

Thanks for the help and I hope this is useful to others in a similar situation!

Comment: Can you accept this as your answer then.